# Wordpress Custom Plugin Fields

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've been trying to go through the codex on creating a custom plugin, i managed to get as far as adding it to the admin panel but i am a little stuck on how to add custom fields to it. for example if i wanted to make a menu plugin, and add items, in the backend i would want to add each item that would be in the menu.
It would need an image, title, description, price. How would i add these fields?
If someone can help me out or even point me to the right reference material or tutorial that would be amazing.

i uploaded the files i did here for reference: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dn31o8nxfd62bo0/menu-plugin.zip?dl=0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good place to start: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

But also, Advanced Custom Fields may provide you with additional features that you could use: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/